# Why It Doesnt Let Me Use Window Open ,What Im Doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, export

```
 function Human(name,currentMail,currentScore,newScore){
 this.name=name || document.querySelectorAll('#e1').value || "Enter Name";
 this.currentMail= currentMail || document.querySelectorAll('#e2').value ||
  "Enter Email";
 this.currentScore=currentScore || document.querySelectorAll('#e3').value || 
 "Enter    Score";
   this.changeScore = function(ns){
                        if (ns!=""){
                        console.log(ns+" Is Your New  Score");
                        this.currentScore=ns;}
                        };

 this.changeMail = function(cmail){
                        if(cmail!=""){
                        console.log(cmail + " Is Your New Mail");
                        this.currentMail = cmail};
                        };
 this.Xport = function(){
                        var exporte=
                        window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
                        exporte.document.writeln("<p>"+ this.name +
                        " "+this.currentMail+
                        " " + this.currentScore "</p>");
                        };                          
  };
 var ilan = new Human();
 ilan.name= "ilan Vachtel";
 ilan.currentMail = "ilanvac@gmail.com";
 ilan.currentScore = "95";
 ilan.newScore = "89";
 ilan.changeScore("89");
 console.log(ilan.currentScore);
 ilan.changeMail("ilanvac@013.net");
 console.log(ilan.currentMail);
 var haim = new Human();
 haim.name = "Haimon";
 haim.currentMail="ilanvac@013.net";
 haim.currentScore="54";
 console.log(haim);
 haim.changeScore("77");
 haim.changeMail("haimvac@gmail.com");
 haim.Xport();
```

This Is A Obect Orientd File in JavaScript That try export Some Stuff from One Window To Another After 
Collect Them From Input Value In the Form Or the manual Input, im always got the "Syntac Error in The Xport Function ,that its not valid , what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Surely the syntax error was giving you the line number? And a link to the line in the dev tools? And telling you that the unexpected token is `this`? Any reasonable browser does.

Comment: it tells me,the position when i try To call the function, the line is at the end (haim.Xport();

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `+` before `this.name`:

```
this.Xport = function(){
                        var exporte=
                        window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
                        exporte.document.writeln("<p>" this.name +" "+this.currentMail+
// Here -----------------------------------------------^
                        " " + This.currentScore "</p>");
                        };                          
};
```

Comment: This Aint working even if i wrote only   exporte.document.write("b");

Comment: @Ilan: Well, you'll just have to work through the rest of the code to figure it out. I stopped at the first glaring error.

Answer (score 0):

Change `This.currentScore` to `this.currentScore` and don't miss `+` in your string concat.

Comment: its aint the problem i change the code here to let you see what im trying to do , i tried it with only exporte.document.writeln("d");     and still got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function